# Comparing two text files to remove duplication of the longer one

Tags: python, file, comparison

I have two files one contains list of data delimited by tab and the second one includes a list of items' id which is one field. I would like to compare each first field in the larger file (file1) with all lines/item id in the smallest file(file2),then if the compared id does not exist in the second file I want to write all the information related to the compared item in the first file(which is the line content separated by tab). I tried the below code but it I have problem with for loops. The first loop doesn't increase while the second for loops all  the second file lines. Also, I want the item number to be written once which is a problem in If statement.

```
for lines in alldata:
  for lines1 in olddata:
    old_data=lines1.split('\r\n')
    dataId=old_data[0]
    data=lines.split('\t')
    photoid=data[0]
    if photoid==dataId:

     break

    else:
     #continue
     #print('matching',lines)
     #break
      w=open(head+'......................../1.txt','a')
      w.write(lines)
```

This is a sample of the files structure:

```
15463774518 2014-10-28 08:12:31 2014-10-28 13:12:31 
15628560471 2014-10-26 07:40:28 2014-10-26 12:40:28 
15444098878 2014-10-26 04:49:19 2014-10-26 09:49:19 
15437269197 2014-10-25 09:55:11 2014-10-25 15:55:11
```

the small file looks like:

```
139747955
2417570005
2478707302
1808883457
211514265
```

Comment: It would be really helpful to see a sample of your file content. Also, can your give a pointer for the size of the files? Are they small enough to be stored in memory?

Comment: The files have different sizes since I am using different size of data, for large file the min. size is 50KB and some of the files are over 5 MB. the smaller files are max.20KB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest following pseudo code. A pythonic way of checking if id file 1 is in id file 2 would be having a list of ids from file 2 and say `if id in idlist:`.

Let's say you have read all ids of the second file to a list `idlist_file2`.
Then you read file one. Parse your line and simply check

```
with open(file1,'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        data = parse_line(line) # function according to your data format, either return a dict or a tuple what ever works best for you
        if date['id'] not in idlist_file2:
             do_something_with_this_info(data)
```

This should give you a good starting point.

Answer (score 0):

I would be tempted to load the second file into a dictionary, then parse the first file and try to match the first column of the lines with the dictionary keys

```
keys_dict = {}
f = open('smallfile.txt','r')
for line in f.readlines():
    keys_dict[line] = 1
f.close()
```

I'm not the super pythonista here but you should get the idea.

Then when you read your big file, check

`if first_column_value in keys_dict:`

Comment: for matching I'll have the problem of \r\n in the dictionary.

Comment: You can remove them with string.replace("\r\n", "") or strip("\r\n")